# How to add jquery current version contents to my current directory?

Tags: jquery

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js

I tried to save the above link contents (i.e jquery-1.12.3.js) to my current directory.

But i got some interrupts while copy and paste it.

Steps which i followed:
```

Copy and paste the contents but the system got hung.

Open gedit and again tried copy and paste.

Comment: Open it in URL in your browser, Right click Save as then save the file in desired location

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download jQuery, you can follow its [homepage download](http://jquery.com/download/) prompts:

> To locally download these files, right-click the link and select "Save
>   as..." from the menu.

if you just click those links directly, what will you see next is its contents in web page, if you want to download it just right click the link and choose `download link file` in the popup menu on mac or `save as...` on windows.

maybe you can use jQuery src attribute in code directly:

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

hope these can help you.

Comment: i tried the above method (it get downloaded) but am unable to open the file it shows windows script host error@Crabime

Comment: sorry，i use mac and can not diagnose such windows exception.